# cameraX Image is already closed while converting imageProxy to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-bitmap, android-camerax

I'm trying to convert the Image captured by take photo method of cameraX into bitmap using below function

```
fun imageProxyToBitmap(image: ImageProxy): Bitmap {

    val buffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer // :- This line is where error was occurring

    buffer.rewind()
    val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(bytes)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
}
```

but It is giving an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed
```

I'm using latest version of cameraX library `"1.0.0-beta11"`

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

this is working fine

```
override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
        var capturedImageBitmap = AppUtils().imageProxyToBitmap(image)
 super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
```

The fix is, one must call `super.onCaptureSuccess(image)` after conversion.

The reason may be this

```
/**
     * Returns the android {@link Image}.
     *
     * <p>If the ImageProxy is a wrapper for an android {@link Image}, it will return the
     * {@link Image}. It is possible for an ImageProxy to wrap something that isn't an
     * {@link Image}. If that's the case then it will return null.
     *
     * <p>The returned image should not be closed by the application. Instead it should be closed by
     * the ImageProxy, which happens, for example, on return from the {@link ImageAnalysis.Analyzer}
     * function.  Destroying the {@link ImageAnalysis} will close the underlying
     * {@link android.media.ImageReader}.  So an {@link Image} obtained with this method will behave
     * as such.
     *
     * @return the android image.
     * @see android.media.Image#close()
     */
```

Comment: Please be noted that in a future release, super.onCaptureSuccess(image) will no longer close the image. Please call image.close() explicitly instead.

Comment: @Xi张熹 That's in future release right ! for version below `1.0.0-beta11` this answer will be valid. But from where you are referring and quoting this ? I need to mark that too give me the link.

Comment: `super.onCaptureSuccess(image)` no longer closes the image starting from version 1.0.0-beta12, you can check the release notes that mention it [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera2-core-lifecycle-1.0.0-beta12).